# Tableau Desktop Filter Disable/Enable

Tags: tableau-api

Working on **Tableau desktop**[Making a visualization] have two filters one cascaded to another.Need a help when making multiple selections in one filter should disable another filter. If one selection is made in a filter then other filter should be enabled and shown.

Looking for answers

[Tableau graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmivb.jpg)

Comment: Can you maybe share an example?

Comment: Please check the question I have added a screenshot of the dashboard the filters is the one I mentioned (managers)-multiple selection should disable (names)

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that if more then one manager is selected, you want no names to be shown?

Comment: Yes that is what I want

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this in a dashboard using the sheet/object swapping and popping technique as explained [here](https://mluttonbi.wordpress.com/2014/10/04/sheet-swapping-and-popping-with-joe-oppelt-and-a-tip-on-searching-the-tableau-forums/). Basically how it works is having a dummy sheet which is empty on a certain condition but which will have values if not. The parameter will be placed below this sheet which results in it moving downwards/upwards whenever the condition changes. Together with a motionless opaque text field it becomes possible to hide the filter. I tested the solution underneath.

You will need a **calculated field** `hide_names` which results in True if the condition is filled. In your case:

```
if COUNTD([Manager]) > 1 then False else True end
```

Next create a **dummy worksheet** which you will fill with another calculated field which does almost nothing e.g. `'a'`. This sheet will be used to 'pop out' the filter in your dashboard. To have this functionality you need to drag the newly created `hide_names` into filters and filter on the custom value `False`.

Now let's look at the **dashboard**.
First bring in the original sheet together with the relevant filters.
Right click the manager filter and select "all using this data source". This way your dummy sheet will also be aware of changes in the filter.
Then create a horizontal floating object in which you need to drag the names filter. On top of the names you need to drag the dummy sheet so if the sheet is active it will push down the second filter.

What you should have now is once you select more than one manager a sheet containing 'a' is shown and the second filter is pushed down. This is not ideal. You will need one or two more things depending on the actual lay-out of your dashboard.

1. You can make your dummy sheet entirely white by changing the format so all rows/columns/text display white, disabling the tooltip and removing headers and titles.
2. Create a new empty floating text object. Right click on it and select format text object. Select white shading for this object. This way it becomes opaque. Drag and change dimensions of this object so it hides the second filter whenever the dummy sheet is shown.

Once you have all of these elements you can sort of play with it to make it work. You can find a demo of a dashboard with similar but not exactly the same functionality [here](http://public.tableau.com/views/PoppingParameters/PoppingParameters?:showVizHome=no&:embed=yes&:tabs=no&:toolbar=no&:revert=&:refresh=yes#1).